# How to code this in a better way

Tags: jquery

I've got this code and I'm looking for a way to write it in a better way. Any sugestions? Thanks.

```
document.querySelector("#botao").onclick = function(){
swal("Title.", "Text.", "info");
 this.onclick=null; };
document.querySelector("#botao2").onclick = function(){
swal("Title.", "Text.", "info");
 this.onclick=null; }; 
document.querySelector("#botao3").onclick = function(){
swal("Title.", "Text.", "info");
 this.onclick=null; };
```

Comment: Actually using jQuery would be a start..  Create a multiple selector and use 'one'.

Comment: You should ask this question on Code Review (it's off-topic on Stack Overflow): http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jQuery

```
 $('#botao, #botao2, #botao3').click( function() {
    swal("Title.", "Text.", "info");
    this.onclick=null; // What's this for?
 });
```

Comment: Assigning null to the inline onclick event property removes the event; eg. the event works once per element. The code will not work the same when switching to jQuery events which work using attached listeners.

Comment: Thanks. It is to show the message only once ( on the first click).